# Find intersections between polygon and horizontal line

Tags: algorithm, math, polygon, computational-geometry

I have a polygon and a given point. I need to find the points on the polygon with the same Y-coordinate as the given point. See attachment: The given point is the red point and the blue points are the points that I am looking for (points that have the same Y as the given points).

At this point of time, I know to solve it by going over the polygon sections and check if the given point Y value relays within that section. After I find the included sections, I just run a simple equation to find the intersections. However! I am looking to find a better and simpler way to solve it, maybe an existing formula for that?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Do you need to find the intersection between a polygon and a horizontal line which goes through the given point? Did I get it right?

Comment: @user2040251 Yes. I need to find the intersection points.

Comment: @Michelle, That is something that I know how to do. I was wondering if there is any wiser formula for doing that.

Comment: @Michelle Thanks, I re-wrote my question.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without iterating over every vertex, though. Any vertex could be on the opposite side of the line from the ones before and after it, so you have to check them all.

Comment: If you have a lot of these queries to answer and the polygon is convex, you can do some preprocessing to speed things up.  Find its topmost and bottommost points (or in fact they can be horizontal lines) and then find the two sequences of edges leading from top to bottom -- one on the left, one on the right.  For each of these two edge sequences, the vertices are in sorted order by y co-ordinate, so when you need to find the intersection for some given y co-ord, you can binary-search each list (O(log n) time) instead of searching every edge (O(n) time).

Comment: In fact convexity is an unnecessarily strong condition for the above algorithm to work -- all you need is for the edges on each side to never go "back up".  Which is good because your example polygon is not convex but (just!) meets this weaker criterion :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker you can do it even if the polygon is concave. Just make a list of segments - you don't care about their connectivity in this case. If the segment is going the wrong direction, reverse it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I think you can still get O(log n) look up time for general polygons if you use a fancier data structure like a segment tree, but I don't see how it would work with just a sorted list of y-coords of vertices...  That will let you find the nearest endpoint on either side, but that endpoint need not belong to an edge that straddles the query y co-ord.

Comment: @MarkRansom: And the set of edges that *do* cross the query y-coord could have endpoints arbitrarily far away from it, so I'm not sure how you could efficiently find them all.  Could you explain more?

Comment: @j_random_hacker you're right, I was solving the wrong problem. I used that algorithm for rendering a polygon, where you need to know *all* the y-coordinate intersections. For just one y coordinate it doesn't work.

Comment: How many sides ? How many points to test per polygon ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses `O(n log n)` time for preprocessing and `O((log n)^2 + cnt)` per query, where `cnt` is a number of intersections. It works for any polygon.

1)Preprocessing: Store each segment as a pair`(low_y, high_y)`. Sort them by `low_y`. Now it is possible to build a two dimensional segment tree where the first dimension is `low_y` and the second dimension is `high_y`. It can take `O(n log n)` space and time if done properly(one can keep a sorted `vector`of `high_y` values for each segment tree node which contains those and only those `high_y` values which correspond to this particular node).

2)Query: It can rephrased in the following way: find all such segments(that is, pairs) which satisfy `low_y <= query_y <= high_y` condition. To find all such segments, one can traverse the segment tree and decompose a range `[min(low_y), query_y]` into a union of at most `O(log n)` nodes(here only the first dimension is considered). For a fixed node, one can apply a binary search over the sorted `high_y` `vector` to extract only those segments which satisfy `low_y <= query_y <= high_y` condition(the first inequality is true because of the way the tree is traversed, so we need to check `high_y` only). Here we have `O(log n)` nodes(due to the properties of a segment tree) and a binary search takes `O(log n)` time. So this step has `O((log n)^2` time complexity. After the smallest `high_y` is found with binary search, it is clear that the tail of the `vector`(from this position to the end) contains those and only those segments which do intersect with the query line. So one can simply iterate over them and find the intersection points. This step takes `O(cnt)` time because a segment is checked if and only if it intersects with the line(`cnt` - total numner of intersections between the line and the polygon). Thus, the entire query has `O((log n)^2 + cnt)` time complexity.

3)There are actually at least two corner cases here:
 i)a point of intersection is a common point of two adjacent polygon sections and
 ii)a horizontal section,
 so they should be handled carefully depending on what is the desired output for them(for example, one can ignore horizontal edges completely or assume that a whole edge is an intersection).

Comment: I'm confused...  All you need is a plain ol' segment tree.  (1) Construct it in O(nlog n) time.  (2) Query it in O(log n + k) time per query, where k is the number of intervals that contain the query y co-ord.

Comment: Each segment has two dimensional nature. It is not possible to unify low_y and high_y. Or, at least I do not see a way to unify them correctly.

Comment: We don't care about x co-ords at all though -- for each edge in the polygon, we can just store its y extent (pair of y co-ords) as a segment in the segment tree, with the x co-ords stored in 2 extra fields (i.e. fields that the segment tree doesn't care about).

Comment: For one dimensional segment tree, it is necessary to maintain a list or a vector of edges for each node(because there can be more than one edge covering concrete y). It is O(n^2) space in the worst case(if all edges are long and cover almost the entire range).

Comment: No, every segment (here, every vertical extent of a polygon edge) will appear at exactly 1 node in the segment tree.  (I had an explanation here of where that is, but it was wrong -- I trust the Wikipedia article though :) )  Here, its x co-ords can be stored in the same place (and treated as a black box by the segment tree functions).

Comment: How does it work on an input like that: (1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, n)(I mean y coordiantes only)? There are at least n / 2 segments contained in at least n / 2 elementary segments(or did i get something wrong?).

Comment: I have just read the wikipedia article. Yes, it is correct. It is possible to answer a query in O(log n + k). I just actually referred to slightly differnt structure when I used segment tree term in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, made another mistake -- each segment will appear at at most 2 nodes on each level in the tree, according to the proof in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).  So it can appear quite a few times -- certainly more than once as I claimed -- but this works out to be still O(nlog n).  I'd suggest trying the construction yourself with your example.  It will start with forming the elementary intervals [1,1], (1,2), [2,2], (2,3), ..., (n-1,n), [n,n].

Comment: Yes, I got it. My solution is basically the same thing, but it is slightly more complex beacause my tree supports find all segments which cover a given segment query, but it unecessary here since a query is always a point.

Answer (score 0):

I assume preprocessing is allowed.

First decompose the polygon in monotone chains: consider all sides in turn and chain all those going in the same direction (up or down). You can ignore the horizontal sides.

There will be at best two chains (always two for convex polygons), and at worst `N-1` or `N` of them (depending on the parity on `N`) if you are really unlucky. On average, four or so.

Note that the vertices in a chain are ordered by increasing or decreasing `Y` (sorting "for free").

Now for a given test point, locate it on `Y` by dichotomy, say between `Yi` and `Yi+1`. Then the intersection is given by `X = Xi + (Y - Yi).(Xi+1 - Xi) / (Yi+1 - Yi)`.

This procedure will require `O(N)` preprocessing time and at worst `O(N)` storage; the query time will be `O(K.LgL)`, where `K` is the number of chains and `LgL` the average logarithm of the chain length.

This is not optimal nor isotropic, but it is pretty simple to program and has little overhead.

[image]

Comment: If `N` is small (say < 10), use the "brute force" approach. Nothing will beat it.